# Xcode 5 issue with simulator versions

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5

I have Installed Xcode 5. It was just working fine. Now it doesn't show version menu against each simulator.

[image]

Before it was displaying all supported iOS versions next to simulator menu. 
I want to test my app on different iOS version, how can I change the simulator version.

Comment: just restart xcode and see, or open any other project and check for the rest of the simulator versions coming or not.

Comment: Already tried this, but unfortunately didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add, you can actually download old versions of the simulator with `Xcode5` itself - just go to preferences and you'll find them under Downloads:.......

[image]

No need to download the zip if you only wanted to change the deployment target.

Here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 5, Preferences -> Downloads -> Components to install additional simulators (if you have not done so already).

Comment: They are already installed but I thinks uninstalling and then re-installing will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Possible issues:

- Set the deployment target. If the target is set to iOS 7.0 then you cannot choose
  between different simulators. If the target is set to iOS 6 then you should be able
  to choose between the simulators.
- Check in the Download preferences if iOS 6 Simulator is installed (you may have to
  re-install it after upgrading to Xcode 5).
- Xcode on Mavericks does not support the iOS 5 Simulator anymore.

Comment: Deployment target is set to 6.1. Seems like i need to re-install Simulator as Upgraded my OS to Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to xcode click show package content and see if simulator sdk's are there at path `"/Applications/Xcode_5.0.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs"` if not either download them or copy paste from previous xCode from same path of old xcode
2. Restart xCode.
3. Check your `Base SDK setting` in project setting. Set to lower version and you should be able to see all possible simulator configuration.